# Switch between INNER JOIN and LEFT JOIN

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have the following query:

```
DECLARE @Cond_ition int = 2

SELECT T.Id, T.Description, T.A_Id, T.B_Id, T.C_Id FROM Table1 as T
JOIN TableA as A ON A.Id = T.A_Id AND A.GroupId = @Cond_ition
JOIN TableB as B ON B.Id = T.B_Id AND B.GroupId = @Cond_ition
JOIN TableC as C ON C.Id = T.C_Id AND C.GroupId = @Cond_ition
```

Columns A_Id, B_Id and C_Id have a low number of distinct values across the rows of T.
The variable @Cond_ition is actually an argument of the stored procedure in which this query needs to run.

The query will only return the rows from T that have a match in A, B and C which is fine except if one or more of these tables don't have a match.
If for example B is empty or has no match with A then the query should return rows from T that have a match with A and C. If B and C are empty then I need the rows from T having a match with A. And if all are empty or have no match then I need all the rows from T.
So, if there is a match it should act as an INNER JOIN but if there is no match it should act like a LEFT JOIN.

Any ideas on how to get this double "effect" from the joins?

*edit: as per request I added sample data

```
Table T  
Id Description A_Id   B_Id    C_Id  
-- ----------- ----   ----    ----  
1  desc1       FANTA  CAN     LIGHT  
2  something2  SPRITE BOTTLE  LIGHT  
3  more3       SPRITE CAN     ZERO  
4  name4       7UP    BOTTLE  ZERO  
5  label5             GLASS   REGULAR  

**Case 1**
Table A
Id     GroupId
--     -------  
FANTA  2
SPRITE 2

Table B
Id   GroupId
--   -------  
CAN  5

*Expected result*
rows 1, 2 and 3

**Case 2**
Table A
Id     GroupId
--     -------  
FANTA  2
SPRITE 2

Table B
Id   GroupId
--   -------  
CAN  2
CAN  5

*Expected result*
rows 1 and 3

**Case 3**
Id     GroupId
--     -------  
FANTA  2
SPRITE 2

Table B
Id   GroupId
--   -------  
CAN  2
CAN  5

Table C
Id   GroupId
--   -------  
ZERO 2

*Expected result*
row 3

**Case 4**
Tables A, B and C empty or no rows with GroupId = 2

*Expected result*
all rows of T
```

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result, all as formatted text, not images. (And take a look at [mcve].)

Comment: So, If there should only be one match then only this one record should be shown, otherwise - if there are no matches - you want to get all records of table1?

Comment: @cars10m yes, that is correct. If there is 1 record that exists in tables A, B or C that has a match then only 1 record from T should be returned

Comment: There is still no [mre] here because we can't cut & paste & run. Also put whatever is needed to ask your question in the post & give a link to where code portions of that were run. If per your comment on an answer you have different code that you are integrating answers to this into, put it in an appropriate question (maybe this one or not), not just at a fiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @gordonlinoff for his input, it helped me to find the solution.
This is the query that meets my requirement:

```
SELECT T.Id, T.Description, T.A_Id, T.B_Id, T.C_Id
FROM Table1 T
JOIN (SELECT Id FROM TableA WHERE GroupId = @Cond_ition
      UNION
      SELECT TOP(1) '' WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT TOP(1) Id FROM TableA WHERE GroupId = @Cond_ition)
     )
  AS A ON ISNULL(T.A_Id,'') = CASE
    WHEN NOT EXISTS (SELECT TOP(1) Id FROM TableA WHERE GroupId = @Cond_ition) THEN ISNULL(T.A_Id,'')
    ELSE A.Id
    END
JOIN (SELECT Id FROM TableB WHERE GroupId = @Cond_ition
      UNION
      SELECT TOP(1) '' WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT TOP(1) Id FROM TableB WHERE GroupId = @Cond_ition)
     )
  AS B ON ISNULL(T.B_Id,'') = CASE
    WHEN NOT EXISTS (SELECT TOP(1) Id FROM TableB WHERE GroupId = @Cond_ition) THEN ISNULL(T.B_Id,'')
    ELSE B.Id
    END
JOIN (SELECT Id FROM TableC WHERE GroupId = @Cond_ition
      UNION
      SELECT TOP(1) '' WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT TOP(1) Id FROM TableC WHERE GroupId = @Cond_ition)
     )
  AS C ON ISNULL(T.C_Id,'') = CASE
    WHEN NOT EXISTS (SELECT TOP(1) Id FROM TableC WHERE GroupId = @Cond_ition) THEN ISNULL(T.C_Id,'')
    ELSE C.Id
    END
```

I use a UNION in the JOIN for each of tables A, B and C.
First Select gets the rows matching the condition, then it unions with a constant if there is no matching record. Using a constant ensures that the result of the UNION is never empty.

In the ON clause of the JOIN I check again with a CASE if there is no matching record in which case I join on the field of T itself (using ISNULL will return me all rows), otherwise I join with the field of the sub-table.

I updated the [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=535fec2210491d160f90bce7783ddfc4) with the query for those who want to check it out.

Answer (score 4):

If I understand correctly, you want only rows with matches, if there are any.  If no rows match at all, then you want all rows from `table1`.

You can handle this using `UNION ALL`:

```
WITH tabc as (
      SELECT T.Id, T.Description, T.A_Id, T.B_Id, T.C_Id
      FROM Table1 T LEFT JOIN
           TableA A
           ON A.Id = T.A_Id AND A.GroupId = @Cond_ition LEFT JOIN
           TableB B
           ON B.Id = T.B_Id AND B.GroupId = @Cond_ition LEFT JOIN
           TableC C
           ON C.Id = T.C_Id AND C.GroupId = @Cond_ition
      WHERE T.A_Id IS NOT NULL OR T.B_Id IS NOT NULL OR T.C_Id IS NOT NULL
     )
SELECT tabc.*
FROM tabc
UNION ALL
SELECT t.*, NULL, NULL, NULL
FROM table1 t
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM tabc);
```

Comment: thanks for your proposed solution. I have not been able to get it working in my environment (there are more joins than just to table A, B or C) so I put an environment up on [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=536aed7c7b25674f72109c69261637f8) covering the 4 cases. Not sure if I'm doing something wrong there but the result is not what I expect, I always get all rows from T returned

Comment: Reading your understanding of my requirement I think I know why it isn't what I'm expecting: if there are matches I only want the rows that match all matches (e.g. case2 and 3 in my samples). I don't want the rows that have "a" match.

Comment: Your input gave me the final nudge to find the solution. I've posted the final query in the answer below